# Hide specific parts of the legend of a line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, legend, angular-nvd3

Is there any way to hide some parts of the legend in a plain line chart using the angular-nvd3 module ?

Actually, the thing is I have several lines and I want that the legend of my dashed lines to be hidden because I don't want the user to be able to select/diselect these dashed lines.

Comment: you can not show the legend from nvd3.. and make your own legends.. that way you can control what is selected or not.

Comment: And can I make that only some part of the legend is selectable or do I need again to reimplement my own legend ?

Comment: we use angular plotly and we implemented our own legends.. i think it's similar because it's also based on d3